# What chrome event listener can be used to get any data posted on webpage especially(file upload)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am not able to get an appropriate event listener. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean "get any data posted on webpage especially"?

Comment: Please expound our question so that community can help you. Also, include what you have done. for the meantime, here's the Official Google Documentation of [Chrome event listener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events) including samples.

Comment: like if i post anything on `facebook` for example status,file or in the gmail i send a file as attachment.I want to get this file and store it.Anything i upload, i want to retrieve it. I am not getting a proper direction , i tried using event listener on submit button . I also tried `webrequest api` but cannot find good way.